# Does --single-transaction and transaction_isolation level set to repeatable-read does same thing

Tags: backup, mariadb

In my my.cnf file Transaction isolation set to repeatable read. I am trying 
--single-transaction  for dump for consistent backup.As per documents --single-transaction sends signal to server as to set  transaction level to repeatable read and then backup gets completed. My question is does I need to use --single-transaction in dump or not? please advise pros and cons  of this.